# Homology group of a Cylinder

Tags: algebraic-topology

There's a simply way to compute the homology group of a cylinder? I try to calculate it with the standard method and the calculations gets harder...

Thanks!

Comment: Try retracting it onto its base.

Comment: What do you mean by standard method?

Comment: The cylinder is a product. The projection onto one factor will induce a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Just in case, the OP might be referring to simplicial homology and may not be familiar with the homotopy equivalence of homologies at all (which is in fact something hard to prove for simplicial homology)

Comment: @BalarkaSen That's a good point.  In that case, the suggestion would be to use the simplicies of the base to create simplicies of the cylinder.